# How can I allow users of my library to override component templates?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written a small component to decorate bootstrap form controls, that will be used in several applications. I'd like to turn this into a library (separate npm package, separate @NgModule), but some applications are likely to want to customize the template. How can I make this easy for them?

My first attempt was extending the component class with a different template in the @Component decorator, but I got:

```
[ERROR ->]<form-control labelKey="Issue.StoryPoints" helpKey="Effort estimate by the development team">
  <in"): ng:///AppModule/EditIssueComponent.html@34:2
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: FormControlComponent,MyFormControlComponent ("
</form-control>
```

I could use a different selector, but changing the selector after the fact means updating all uses in templates, and assigning a distinct selector up front reminds me of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) ...

Is there a better way I am missing?

It seems odd for a framework that makes overriding providers so easy to have no support for overriding components :-(

Comment: so you just want to override the styles or html elements too

Answer (score 2):

Your components are supposed to act like 'black-boxes'. `Inputs` and `Outputs` and maybe some public methods. If the user of your component is able to edit a template, this would mean he would need deep knowledge of the internal structure of your component. There are certain ways though in which a user would be able to change the behaviour/structure of your component:

If you want the user to have the ability to add some extra `html/template` at certain places, you can use the `ng-content` tag within your component's template.

If you want the user to be able to just change certain behaviour of the public api of your component, you can use `extend` without an `@Component` decorator.

If you want the user to have to ability to build his own component, on top of yours, they can opt for using a wrapper around your component, or extend your component with their own `@Component`, and with it their own prefix selector.